# Django - filtering objects with a field that has a value with spaces in it not working?

Tags: python, django, slug

I'm trying to get urls working in django to display all items that have a field equal a certain value. The field on my model is a charfield, like this:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

I am not using slugfields or anything like that (I don't know what the point of them is?), and I cannot seem to get filtering working when the value of the series field has spaces in it. My view looks like this:

```
def series(request, slug):
    print slug
    tag = slug.replace("-", " ")
    print tag 
    print Episode.objects.filter(series=tag)

    return render(request, "taggedpage.html", {   
        "episodes": Episode.objects.filter(series=tag),
        "tag": tag

        })
```

my url pattern:

```
url(r'^series/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','galleries.views.series', name='series'),
```

For example, if the series field is equal to "the sopranos", trying to visit the url

```
http://mytvsite.com/series/the-sopranos/
```

returns no objects. However, if the field is only one word, it works fine, e.g if the series was "house", visiting

```
http://mytvsite.com/series/house/
```

would return all the objects with a series: field value of house. 
Is this some regex/slug thing?

Comment: Don't know, without seeing the relevant URL pattern.

Comment: my mistake, added it in

Comment: what does `print Episode.objects.filter(series=tag)` return ?

Comment: returns an empty set [] - don't know why, there is an object with 'the sopranos' as the series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was causing the problem exactly, but I installed [django-autoslug](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug/1.7.2) and it all works now.